# How to see all packages of given author on http://pub.dartlang.org?

Tags: package, dart, usability

I cannot find way how to see all packages of given author on http://pub.dartlang.org

For example, if I want see all packages of `caolan` on https://www.npmjs.org I can click on the author link and go to author page https://www.npmjs.org/~caolan.

As far as I know, packages on http://pub.dartlang.org also has their own authors.

That is, they has rightful owners.

For some reason I could not find a way to get an overall picture about the packages relatively of their authors.

- Is this possible?
- If not possible then why?

P.S.

I am amazed at all the paucity of services provided to http://pub.dartlang.org.

The impression is that nobody does this because they simply do not care about it.

Maybe there is an argument in favor of the fact that I'm wrong?

I do not think that requires huge investments.

Comment: Have you considered filing a feature request on http://dartbug.com/new under Area-PubSite?

Comment: Well, to answer your question: It's not possible now, It is obviously possible to implement, so the reason it's not possible is that that feature has not been added to pub. The way to actually get it added is to file a feature request, and get other people to show interest in it as well. Not all feature requests are implemented, no matter how reasonable they seem to the person requesting them. Just check the language feature requests I have made that have never materialized :)

Answer (score 4):

Pub site doesn't have such feature for now.

However the sources of http://pub.dartlang.org are available on https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang/ . You can help to improve the service by submitting Pull-Requests.

You can alternatively use the json output of http://pub.dartlang.org/packages.json and http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/xxx.json to achieve what you want. I made that and you can see a raw result at http://a14n.github.io/pub-infos/packages-by-uploader.html. The collected json datas are available at http://a14n.github.io/pub-infos/datas.json. (The sources: https://github.com/a14n/pub-infos )

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible yet. There have been some mentions of improving the pub site. However, nothing has happened as of yet.